# Is it possible to run multiple instances/windows of Finder in Mac OS X?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, windows-explorer, finder, multiple-instances

Mac OS X's [Finder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finder_%28software%29) seems to be the equivalent to Windows Explorer. In Windows, I enjoy having multiple instances of Explorer open to move/copy files from one folder in a window, to another folder in another window.

How can I achieve this in [Snow Leopard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Snow_Leopard)?

I'd like to have a shortcut key, as well as a dock icon solution. Or maybe there's a better program than Finder out there that does this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd>

Opens new Finder windows....I think you can do what you are asking by just doing that...

Comment: I'll have to try that when I get home.  Is there a dock icon equivalent?-- I'd like to open a brand new window every time the dock icon is clicked.

Comment: There's also a Finder preference for opening folders in their own windows.

Comment: OMG!! it took 4 year to me, think that its possible, and i got you answer, Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

If you right-click (or <kbd>Control</kbd>-click) on the finder icon in the dock, the first option in the menu is "New Finder Window", which will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Command</kbd>-double-click a folder in the Finder to open it in a new window, leaving the old window still open.

It's certainly possible to create an applescript to open a new finder window and put it in the finder toolbar, but I don't see the point given this open folder in a new window shortcut and the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard shortcuts rock!

Triple button combination: Option+Command+Spacebar Opens a new finder... or keep pressing for multiple finders.

Spotlight on the Mac (and therefore one of the quickest ways to find just about any file or program) is just Command+SPacebar.

WindowsKey+E does the same on PC for a new Explorer window and with Vista/Win7, just hit the Windows key and you're right in the search box and ready to go.

Using Windows 7 and Snow Leopard back to back on a daily basis, I cringe at how cludgy Mac's finder interface is, double cringe at how so many mac user's don't know the shortcuts that ease the cludginess, and then tripple cringe when mac users think everything on a Mac is better than PC.  Sorry, they both have dark sides to their personality.  Finder is not exactly one's of Mac's brightest moments.

Comment: Option + Cmd + Space opens a new search window in Finder... or you could just use Cmd + N to open a new window.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you're using multiple windows mainly for moving/copying files, whether a finder plugin that enables tabs in finder would be useful? I use TotalFinder: http://totalfinder.binaryage.com/

It's not free, but I find it relatively bug free, and it also has some other useful features like a keyboard shortcut for showing hidden files. I'm sure there are other alternatives.

I find using tabs to manipulate files easier then multiple windows, but your opinions may vary.

Comment: +1 I do use it for move/copying files. I finder the default MacOSX Finder to be rather basic/dull, so now I use [Binary Night's Forklift](http://www.binarynights.com/). Thanks for your suggestion.